# Clickable circle and text in linear layout?

Tags: android, styles, android-linearlayout, shapes, clickable

I am using a style within a linear layout to create a clickable circle with text--representing a day of the week. I am making the shape just fine, though the click functionality is not working properly.

Here is my **linear layout**:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        style="@style/circleButton_style"

        android:saveEnabled="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="S"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

My **style**:

```
<style name="circleButton_style" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/circle_stand_sel</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">48dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">5dp</item>
</style>
```

And my **drawable**:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- initial state state -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/circle" android:state_first="false" />

<!-- disabled state -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/circle" android:state_enabled="false"/>

<!-- enabled and pressed state -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/circle_pressed" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>

<!-- enabled and focused state -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/circle_pressed" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true"/>

<!-- enabled state -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/circle_pressed" android:state_enabled="true"/>
```

It is not moving the circle_pressed state at all, and I don't know why.. can anyone help?

Comment: Have you intentionally left off some code on the drawable xml or is that the contents of the file? i.e. the closing selector tag etc..

Comment: yeah, my bad. the code functions, though it just shows me the "circle" drawable and isn't allowing any click functionality

Comment: Oh ok cool, have you tried adding clickable to the textview also? I can't see anything obviously wrong here!

Answer (score 0):

`state_first`, `state_middle`, and `state_last` are used for creating different styles for the first, middle, or last items in a certain ViewGroups. There's not too much documentation, so I don't know where they are used.

Each item in the selector is evaluated sequentially and the first item that matches is applied. So, basically, your first item is always matched. Your default state should be the last item on the list:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/circle_pressed"
          android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/circle_pressed"
          android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/circle"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: I guess these selectors are not supported by default on any components: https://sriramramani.wordpress.com/2014/03/13/pseudo-selectors/

Comment: With this code you provided I can hold the circles and they color, though they will not change on click @karaokyo

Comment: I think i can do this programmatically by setting an onClick method to setEnabled

Comment: I guess part of the problem is that you're doing it on a LinearLayout, which doesn't have an enabled state.

Comment: then what should I be using?

Comment: Button? Do you actually need an enabled state?

Comment: Well it's changing colors when I hold it but when I let go it goes back to the "circle" image

Comment: So basically, you need a `RadioGroup` with your drawable applied to each `RadioButton`.